# Extracting Most Read Titles with BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the titles in the Most Read section of a news page. This is what I have so far, but I'm getting all the titles. I just want the ones in the Most Read section.

`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.michigandaily.com/section/opinion'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")

for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_= "views-field views-field-title"):
    if story_heading.a:
        print(story_heading.a.text.replace("\n", " ").strip())
    else:
        print(story_heading.contents[0].strip())`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit your scope to only the div container for the most read articles.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.michigandaily.com/section/opinion'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")

most_read_soup = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'view-id-most_read'})[0]

for story_heading in most_read_soup.find_all(class_= "views-field views-field-title"):
    if story_heading.a:
        print(story_heading.a.text.replace("\n", " ").strip())
    else:
        print(story_heading.contents[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector to get the specific tags from the top most read div:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.michigandaily.com/section/opinion'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
css = "div.pane-most-read-panel-pane-1 a"
links = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select(css)]
```

Which will give you:

```
[u'Michigan in Color: Anotha One', u'Migos trio ends 2016 SpringFest with Hill Auditorium concert', u'Migos dabs their way to a seminal moment for Ann Arbor hip hop', u'Best of Ann Arbor 2016', u'Best of Ann Arbor 2016: Full List']
```